# Need Guidance with some Python code (Substitute Cypher Python)

Tags: python, encryption

I have some code already but I got feedback on how to pass the rest of the criteria but I have no idea how to do it.

Assignment brief:

You are working in a Newspaper office that handles the reports from their journalists. You have been asked to design a program that will be used to help them send confidential reports in that others cannot read as email is not secure, we need to generate an encryption key that they can encode their scoops and documents when sent by email.
The program will need to generate the key. Encode the message, export the key, import a key from another person and decode a message. It will be a simple substitution cipher. The key needs to be made up out of all Alphanumeric Characters and some Special Characters. It will be a single key per session so you will need to save the key if you close the program otherwise you won’t be able to decode those messages used to encode them.
All projects start with planning it is the most important part that can make or break a project so ensure this is carried out correctly

[Pass, Merit and Distinction Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJr1S.png)

What the feedback says to do:

You were asked to import a key and export a key your program doesn't allow this so you would need to resubmit to get Pass4 and Pass6

Code I have done so far below

```
def run():
    x=input("code or decode? ")
    if x == "code":
        a=list("")
        import string
        alpha = str("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        message=input("What is your message to encode? ")
        x=len(message)
        y=0
        z=0
        for counter in range(x):
            y=y+1
            letter = alpha.find(message[z:y])
            z=z+1
            letter=letter+13
            if letter > 24:
                letter=letter-24
            letter=alpha[letter:letter+1]
            if counter != x-1:
                print(letter,end="")
            else:
                print(letter)
        x=input("type yes to go again? ")
        if x == "yes":
            run()
        else:
            input()

    else:
        a=list("")
        import string
        alpha = str("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        message=input("What is your message to decode? ")
        x=len(message)
        y=0
        z=0
        for counter in range(x):
            y=y+1
            letter = alpha.find(message[z:y])
            z=z+1
            letter=letter-13
            if letter < 0:
                letter=24+letter
            letter=alpha[letter:letter+1]
            if counter != x-1:
                print(letter,end="")
            else:
                print(letter)
        x=input("again? ")
        if x == "yes":
            run()
        else:
            input()

run()
```

Comment: It looks like you implemented rot-13 (?) while they're asking you for a monoalphabetic substitution cipher.

Comment: It sounds like you're not clear on what is meant by a "key" and a "substitution cipher", and the assignment is assuming that you know what those concepts mean and have some idea how to implement them.  I suggest going back and reviewing the earlier coursework; it was probably covered in assigned reading, a lecture, earlier assignments, or more likely all three.

Comment: I wasn't there for the lesson and we don't record the lessons online so i have no idea since there are no videos i can find, if you have any videos on yt please send them my way

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and come up with this.

You can use it as it is or edit it to meet your needs. Hope it helps.

**Update.1:** The longer the message, the bigger the encryption key will be. One solution for this is to use zlib.compress method in order to shrink the key, and then decompress it when needed.

**Update.2:** Added the export/import functionality of the encryption key using a Json file (you can of course choose other way of storing data) along with a title assigned to it, so you have the choice to either enter the title or enter the encryption key of the message for decryption. The title is just optional and for simplicity purposes, you can get rid of it if you want to. You'll also notice the code contains lots of if/else statements, that's just so you know where you currently are and what choices you have.

A GUI based would be better.

```
import string
import json
import os
# A list containing all characters
alpha = string.ascii_letters

def code(title, message, key = 6):
  temp_dict = {}
  cipher=[]
  
  for i in range(len(alpha)):
      temp_dict[alpha [i]] = alpha [(i+key)%len(alpha )]
    
  # Generating the encryption key
  for char in message:
      if char in alpha :
          temp = temp_dict[char]
          cipher.append(temp)
      else:
          temp =char
          cipher.append(temp)
           
  # This code is needed to decode the expected message so make sure to save it by any method you want,
  # otherwhise it'll generate a random text.
  cipher= "".join(cipher)
  main_data = {title : cipher}

  file_name = "encryption_key.json"

  if os.path.exists(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r+") as file:
      data = json.load(file)
      data[0].update(main_data)
      file.seek(0)
      json.dump(data, file)
  else:
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
      json.dump([main_data], file)

  print("Encryption code :",cipher)
  

def decode(cipher, key = 6):
  temp_dict = {}    
  
  for i in range(len(alpha)):
      temp_dict[alpha [i]] = alpha [(i-key)%(len(alpha ))]
        
  # Decoding the message
  decoded_text = []
  for char in cipher:
      if char in alpha :
          temp = temp_dict[char]
          decoded_text.append(temp)
      else:
          temp = char
          decoded_text.append(temp)
           
  decoded_text = "".join(decoded_text)
  return decoded_text

while True:
  # There is an optional parameter (key) within the function which you can change according to your preference.
  # The default value is 5 and it needs to be the same in both encode and decodefunctions.
  x=input('[E]ncode or [D]ecode? answer with "e/d:" ')
  if x.lower() == "e":
    title = input("Enter the title of the message: ")
    message = input("What is your message to encode? ")
    code(title, message)
    break
  elif x.lower() == "d":
    
    file_name = "encryption_key.json"
    if os.path.exists(file_name):
      with open(file_name, "r+") as file:
        data = json.load(file)[0]
    else:
      print("There is no related file for decryption.")
      continue

    choice = input('Enter the [T]itle or the [K]ey of the message for decryption. [A]ll to decrypt everything on the file. answer with "t/k/a:" ')
    if choice.lower() == 't':
      title = input("Enter the title: ")
      if title in data.keys():
        encryption_key = data[title]
        print(decode(encryption_key))
        break
      else:
        print("There is no such title.")

    elif choice.lower() == "k":
      encryption_key = input("Enter the encryption code related to the message? ")
      if encryption_key in data.values():
        print(decode(encryption_key))
        break
      else:
        print("There is no such encryption key.")
    
    elif choice.lower() == "a":
      decrypt_dict = {}
      for k, v in data.items():
        decrypt_dict[k] = decode(v)
      print(decrypt_dict)
      break

    else:
      print("There is no related file for decryption.")

  else:
    print("Enter a valid answer.")
```

Comment: thanks for the improvement, although one of the requirements is to export/import the encryption key, also this doesn't allow you to enter a key in to decrypt it

Comment: @EvanBrown I've updated the code for export/import, check it out.

Comment: It is not good practice to supply complete answers for homework questions, especially when it's not clear the original poster has done anything on his own to solve the problem.  We shouldn't be doing their homework.

Comment: @TimRoberts I know what you mean, but since I've never tried something like this, I decided to give it a shot, and who knows I could learn something new about it too